# MVC3 Razorview syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have the following in my view:

```
    @{ var index = 0; }
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    ...
    @{ 
         index += 1; 
     }
    }
```

but i get

> No overload for method 'Write' takes 0
>   arguments

what gives?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i believe it should be...

```
@{ var index = 0; }
@foreach (var item in Model)
{

     index += 1; 

}
```